# Just started working with uBuntu and came across this after running, "sudo apt upgrade"

Tags: apt, upgrade

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsystemd-shared libsystemd0 libudev1 systemd systemd-oomd systemd-resolved systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd udev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
```

also just upgraded from 23.04 to 23.10, this wasn't ann issue on 23.04

Comment: Pick two or three of those listed packages. Run `apt policy <packagename>` for each. Copy the entire output. [Add that output](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1493456/edit) into your question above.